# Should I publishing Go module if the changes is non Go code?

Tags: go, go-modules

This is a silly question, but anyway, should I publish Go module if I just change non Go code like README, Github Actions, or even a comment in the Go code? or just push the change in the branch but leave the tag until next breaking, major, or minor changes?

Comment: Why leave in a branch? I'd even merge readme and comment changes right away. But yes, without substantial changes, it doesn't make sense to release a new version.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I publishing Go module if the changes is non Go code?

Yes. This is exactly what minor version increments are for. See https://semver.org/

No, this is not a matter of opinion. If your fixes to documentation etc. are only on master/develop, they may be mixed with other changes which are incompatible with the version I am using, and I won't be able to know without extensive research of the project's commit history.

Comment: That spec talks about functionality. I'd argue that changes in README and code comments do not affect functionality at all.